# How to change background color of grid's dirty cells in Extjs

Tags: extjs, grid, styling, cells

I want to change the style (background color... etc) of dirty cells in the grid. How to apply a style that will affect only the dirt cells of a grid ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following CSS class name for changing some of the property of dirty cells :

```
.x-grid3-dirty-cell {
     background-image:none;
}
```

This will remove the red corner from the dirty cells.This is applicable ExtJs version>=3

If you want to change the background color of cell, you have to use `x-grid3-cell-inner`
you can use `columnRenderer`, where you can write the logic. As cell is edited, columnrenderer will be called, and there you can check if value is changed, change the color using

```
function columnrenderer(value, meta,records,rowIndex,colIndex,store,view){
    var column = view.getHeaderAtIndex(colIndex);
    var dataIndex = column.dataIndex;
    records.modified[dataIndex]; //Will give the original value
    value; //gives the changed value
    if(//both are not same)
         return '<div class="x-grid3-cell" style="background-color:red;"><span >(' + value + ')</span></div>';
    else
       //do nothing
}
```

For more information on GridCellRenderer see [ExtJs Grid FAQ](http://www.sencha.com/learn/grid-faq/)

Comment: Any folder which contains a `css` file. in that css file, put these classes. Refer to the css file in your `index.html`. This is the class name, used by ExtJs framework. it will get overriden.

Comment: added to css file still no change